# How to make an s3 object public in s3 private bucket without using presigned URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I have an s3 bucket with the following policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

also the bucket public access is blocked. here is a snapshot of bucket policy

[image]

Basically I want the bucket to be private in order to prevent unauthorized users from uploading files but I would like to grant public read access to the objects inside the bucket for any user

Comment: CloudFront + OAI could be an option

Comment: is there is another other than cloudfront.

Comment: For unauthorized users, do you mean anonymous user?

Comment: yes it should be for anonymous user

Comment: Ok, turn off the "block all public access" then. You just need to allow `s3:GetObject` for anonymous user.

Comment: But this will prevent authorized users from uploading and deleting object to bucket. I want authorized users to upload and delete and anonymous users to read only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you want to allow *anyone* to retrieve an object, but they should not be allowed to do anything else.

There are two ways to accomplish this:

**1. Using ACLs**

You could assign a `public-read` ACL to the individual objects. This also requires S3 Block Public Access to be deactivated for the two ACL-related options.

In this way, your bucket remains private but the objects are accessible if the name of the object is known. (Listing is not enabled.)

**2. Using a Bucket Policy**

This policy will allow anyone to access objects in the bucket:

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

It will permit any attempt to get an object, but will not allow listing, deleting, etc.

For BOTH the above options, if you want "authorized" users to be able to do things like upload and delete objects, then those permissions should be **assigned directly to the IAM Users** (without using an S3 Bucket Policy).